# Can't get the switch node to accept my value input

Tags: geometry-nodes

I'm new to Blender and geometry nodes. I've made this simple node tree which is supposed to populate a mesh with two different objects based on a simple piece of math on the index. My problem is, I can't seem to find a way to connect the switch. I was sure the "compare" node outputs a boolean value and I believe the switch nodes is expecting a boolean - can anyone see what I am doing wrong?

Thanks in advance!

Jeppe

[image]

Comment: Related: [Why is there a red line when I try to connect one node to another?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/274557/)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The switch node can only take a single value as an input, you are trying to pass a field to it. Instead of using a switch node I recommend the following:

1. Replace both object info nodes with one collection info node, that encompass all objects you want to place on grid.
2. Plug the modulo directly into instance index.

this way you get the flowing result.
[image]

Comment: Thank you so much @jst kiko - you are a life-saver - this was a much better solution!