# Randomize values for each nested Geonode?

Tags: geometry-nodes, geometry, random

I have a nested geonode of generated plants, and I want to randomize these plants with another geonode.

But once I plug into a random value into the instanced plant, it shows me an error.

Is there a way to work around this? Or am I not doing something right...

[Here's my file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1-CmFEbdUscV0IuCclOYNncg5_S2VHpYA/view?usp=share_link)

[image]

[image]

Comment: Hello! This question has been asked many times in different variations. A good explanation, why this unfortunately does not work and what other options are available to you, can be found here: [How can I instantiate a procedural node group with different parameters?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/274485/145249). The following post may also help you: [Why is there a red line when I try to connect one node to another?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/274557).