# How to set random botttom or top Cone radius in Geometry nodes

Tags: geometry-nodes, procedural

[image]

Im trying to create random top radius, but when im trying to put Random value in the socket and because random value has circle output and Cone Radius input has diamond shape they dont work

[image]

I somewhere read that i should put interget node into ID socket, it createt diamond with dot output but when connected this there is no any randomness. Can someone explain why does it happen? Thank you, ive been searching for the answer almost 2 days :)

Comment: Hello & welcome to https://blender.stackexchange.com/. There are two things playing together here: On the one hand, the types of the inputs/outputs differ (This is explained here: [Why is there a red line when I try to connect one node to another?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/274557)) and on the other hand, you apparently want to instantiate the cone multiple times with random parameters (This problem is described here: [How can I instantiate a procedural node group with different parameters?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/274485)).

Comment: ...These are two different problems, yet I mark the question as duplicate, because this is primarily about the red connecting line. Feel free to edit the post, and reopen your question if necessary. Thank you!