# Geometry Node - recursion

Tags: geometry-nodes, random

I'm a bit new on blender and I want to make a building but with random size.
The first try was to make a vertical grid with a random on "vectices Y" but this field dont accept random numbers.

The second try was to make it recursively : GN know how many stage left to do, it make a stage and if there is more to make, I call himself asking one less. Again, blender dont accept recursion ... Even with 2 same Geometry Node calling themself. WHY Blender ! Why :'( !

Did you have any idea how to make this ?

Thanks !

---

Thanks for the first answer.

I would like to generate a city with different buildings over a grid but with random size for each building.
In you first link (good link I keep it!), I see that I need an ID and that's the thing I was guessing a bit. But if I put one directly, all buildings are the same.

But considering the first grid, can we get a different ID for each point generated?

[image: a minimalistic version of my GN]

Comment: Hello and welcome to https://blender.stackexchange.com/! Please take a closer look at the following posts: [Why is there a red line when I try to connect one node to another?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/274557)) and [How can I instantiate a procedural node group with different parameters?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/274485). Maybe this will help you. If not, please be so kind and explain more precisely what the problem is, what you have tried so far, and supplement the question with pictures or your blend file. Thank you!

Comment: Regarding your update: Exactly this problem is described in the second link.

Comment: So, because I have possibly 100 kind of return, I have to put 100 new nodes. I'll make a group, I already have approximately 20 nodes on my sheet (and I'll make variations of this 100 buildings). Thank you!

Comment: You're welcome! Feel free to edit and reopen the question at any time if clarification is needed.