# Dashed Red Noodle after Compare Node

Tags: geometry-nodes

As can be seen from the attached image, I'm getting a red noodle immediately after using a Compare node.  This isn't entirely surprising, as I'm obviously trying to connect a diamond with a circle at that spot.  However, as can be seen, I'm using a Sample Index immediately prior to that, which I thought was the way to obtain the specific attribute value that I need to use in the Compare node.  As such, I'm now very confused about what's actually going on here and what I need to do to fix it.  So, any suggestions?  I'm using v3.4.

Thanks in advance.

[image: Node group with dashed red noodle after a Compare node]

Comment: I think you want to plug a single value node in the Sample Index's Index input

Comment: I can see that this would make the red noodle go away, but I don't think the nodes, as a whole, would work as intended then.  I want to evaluate an attribute on each of the point features, to decide whether they're going to be output or not.  So, I surely need the index for that?  Maybe the Switch node isn't as versatile as I need it to be.  I'm not sure what the alternative to that is, though.  It's hard to know what to look for.

Comment: As long as you feed the node `Sample Index` with a field, you will always get a red line. `Switch` requires a single value for a geometry. You can force this by feeding the `Sample Index` node with a single value at the *Index* input. Read more here: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/274557

Comment: It depends on what the switch node is linked to. You may want to populate a boolean field with True / False and use that as a selection mask on a instance on points node for instance ?