# Geometry Nodes - Distance Comparison to trigger Geometry Switch

Tags: node-editor, geometry

[image]I've been working on a node setup for a while and I cannot for the life of me figure out how to trigger a boolean with a distance comparison.

I'm trying to have the the instance geometry switched based on there distance from an object.

I may be searching incorrectly, but none of what I can find shows how to solve this. So I'm stuck really, and I need some help here. I'm sure its simple, but I'm not the most "logic", or "node" savvy person. Please let me know if you have more info or ideas!

Comment: This might be helpful: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/274557/

Comment: Thanks for Responding @quellenform! 

That's the part I'm kind of struggling with. Its giving me a diamond which the link you gave says diamonds are putting out a field attribute, but the [manual](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/modeling/geometry_nodes/utilities/compare.html) is saying that the output for the Compare Node is a standard boolean.

I think I'm not understanding the context of what boolean the "Compare Node" is producing and why the Switch Node "Boolean" Socket is not accepting the input.