# Procedural Book Shelf geometry nodes

Tags: geometry-nodes, procedural

I am trying to make a procedural bookshelf that can be modified by some parameters I input. I was able to create the book with these variable parameters and duplicate it like an array modifier, but I don't know how to make each duplicate to have random values for each individual book.

[image]

[image]

This is what I have so far also I would really like to know why the *Combine XYZ* node doesn't transfer the data to the transform node.

Comment: There's a full tutorial on doing that [here](https://youtu.be/_RgQjAXLZNg) Part 2 covers the randomizing and fitting to a bookshelf section. I think it uses Blender 3.5 though.

Comment: @JohnEason I was just looking for the link myself, I would recommend the tutorial for this (CG) matter as well 

Comment: Thank you, I did watch the video, cause that is how I started working on this project, but in his version he is making them appear with the frame count, and is using simultation nodes, which don't work in my case, cause i need to imput the no. of duplicates separately, but thanks for the answear, much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could convert the geometry of the book into an instance with `Geometry to Instance`, duplicate it with `Duplicate Elements`, and then modify it with the `Scale Instances` and `Transform Instances` nodes.

Something like this:

[image]

To answer your question, why you cannot use the mode `Combine XYZ` in this way:

The node `Transform` requires a single value, but `Combine XYZ` in this case returns a [field](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/modeling/geometry_nodes/fields.html), i.e. multiple values, because of the preceding nodes.

Here you can read more about this topic:
[Why is there a red line when I try to connect one node to another?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/274558/145249)

Comment: Thank you so much, this solution actually worked, and thanks a lot for the explanation as well.