# Capture Position and work with that

Tags: geometry-nodes

I want to capture the position of each instance created by an instance on points node and use this data to manipulate the object on this position.

To explain what this nodes setup shell do:

The Bezier is placed on a circle to create a vase. This process is not well done but it works. The original setup i did is to adjust the parameters for a single vase and then render only that vase. Now i want to create a matrix of vase to get a viraty and since i dont want to place 25 vase on my own and adjust there parameters individually. I thought it might be a good idea to make a matrix out of it.

Further down the node tree there is a setup which captures the values given for a vase and displays it for rendering next to it so i can see what parameters create a shape i want to work with further.

Thank you for your help.

[image: current node setup]

So lets say parameter 1, influenced by the position, should be the roundness and parameter 2 is the rough edge at the top.
The matrix shell now manipulate those parameter based on there position. I think the index would also kinda work but in both cases i dont realy know how to do that. I hope this sketch helps a bit.

[image]

Explanation:

Lets start with the grid. It starts at 0.0.0 and goes up to lets say 5.0.0 in the x directio and 0.5.0 in the y direction. The grid has now 25 (5 x axis points times 5 y axis points) grid points where i can place an objet with the instances on points node. On each of this points i want to create a vase now. The vase has 2 parameters. 1 Parameter sets the curveture of the Vase at the top half and makes it bigger as i increase this parameter. Lets call it TopCurve. Then i have another parameter which influences the bottom half of the vase. Lets call it BottomCurve.

Now both parameters start at the value 0 and go up to the value 2 in float number range. Now i want to manipulate or directly create the vases in the grid with variations of these parameters BottomCurve and TopCurve. So at the coordinates 0.0.0 is a vase which has the parameters BottomCurve = 0 and TopCurve = 0. Following this setup i want to map TopCurve along the x axis and BottomCurve along the y axis. The matrix created by this has now a vase with BottomCurve = 0, TopCurve = 0 at 0.0.0 a vase with BottomCurve = 0 and TopCurve = 2 at 5.0.0

Therefore a the vase at 0.5.0 has the parameters BottomCurve = 2 and TopCurve = 0 and at 5.5.0 the vase hast both parameters with the value 2. The individual steps between those endpoints in the matrix (grid) are then created with the help of this matrix. So i give the Matrix 2 parameters with what i want the vases to be manipulated with and a grid size (in the example 5 steps) and it creates the 25 shapes on there position. The reason why i want to use the position is because i thaught it migth be the best solution to create such a matrix but other ways are possible too.

Comment: you are capturing the position of the points - instead of instances. Change point to instance on your capture attribute node. and pls...next time use an image which is sharper so we don't have to hurt our eyes, thx.

Comment: Thank you for the answer but unfortunetly i have to tell you i already tryed that and it changes nothing ;D

Comment: @Chris I have updated the picture, sorry. I only have a laptop to work with and didn't wan't to fuse multiple pictures together.

Comment: @Alec At first glance I see that there are red lines connected to the _Bézier Segment_ node, indicating an error. The reason is, this node creates a single segment and can only have one _Start Handle_ and one _End Handle_, but you are plugging fields of (= multiple) values into the sockets.

Comment: Maybe helpful: [Why is there a red line when I try to connect one node to another?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/274557/)

Comment: @Alec: if you don't know - you shouldn't make wrong comments, but ask. You captured each point after you instanced on points, that will give you the points of zeros if you would have used the viewer -> [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wh2Dl.jpg if you are using instance, you get the right values: [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/AQrU1.jpg but yeah, you can write : i tried that and it didn't work (that's because you made several mistakes, the other one was that, what gordon wrote) ....so maybe you should think a bit more or ask before commenting wrong things

Comment: Thank you @quellenform i've worked through the link you provided. The only thing i see where it could be an issue is the fact that i am dealing with multiple values at the same time. Will say: i have no index involved in this scenario but i dont know if i could implement that, if it would be usefull and especially how. 
Currently, imo i am taking the position of each point in the grid and use it for further calculations or am i wrong here?

Comment: @GordonBrinkmann Ah! Thanks. I see. So now i need to figure out how to seperate the field into individual positions. Maybe working with the index might be an option?

Comment: Yes, correct: Currently you are capturing the positions of the individual instances. So you have several values. Maybe it would be helpful if you sketch how the final result should look like, so we can better understand what you actually want to do. But probably you will want to instantiate the curves first, then realize them and move their points. That's where the node `Sample Index` will help you.

Comment: @Alec Sure, this way you could separate the positions by index. But this would still mean you would need a _Bézier Segment_ node for each position, to create a segment for each index. I would rather say you have to instance the segment and manipulate the handles afterwards.

Comment: @GordonBrinkmann Ok i see. The Bezier is then processed into a vase shape and i want to manipulate the curveture of the Bezier to get another shape of the vase. Is there a way to manipulate the curveture afterwards so that it is not randome like with a noise texture?

Comment: @quellenform i've updated the question ;)

Comment: Thank you, and I would love to help you, but I can't figure out your nodes. At least it's not clear to me what the result should be, so I would ask you again to sketch it out. As the question currently stands, it's an [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) and it's unclear which solution leads to the desired goal.

Comment: @quellenform done. I hope it helps.

Comment: I'm sorry to say this, but I just can't figure out what exactly the goal is supposed to be. I have now rebuilt the entire node tree (it would be good if you could share your blend file with https://blend-exchange.com/ in the future), but it's still not clear from your sketch what EXACTLY the result should look like. Please try to make this more precise and share your file. Thanks for your understanding!

Comment: @quellenform I hope i could clear things up