# Vary Geometry Node Instances

Tags: geometry-nodes

I'm using geometry nodes to generate different structures on a flat plane. Here's what it looks like right now:

[image: top-down view of the structures on the plane.]

As you can see, all the structures look the same. Each structure is defined by a group of geometry nodes which looks like this:

[image: the geometry nodes that generate each structure.]

The plane itself uses geometry nodes that look like this:
[image: the geometry nodes of the plane.]

I want to vary the height of each structure, but every time I use a random value, it comes out red.

[image: Error with random value node.]

I want to use a random value **for each structure instance**. How would I do that?

Comment: Maybe helpful: [Why is there a red line when I try to connect one node to another?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/274557/)