# field of random values on circle socket

Tags: geometry-nodes

a question that might seem very silly but for which I can't find any obvious solutions.
To illustrate the problem, I'd like to use different random values on each instance of a grid. For example, how do you get a grid of spheres, each with a different radius since i can not plug a diamond and a circle socket (see picture) ?
Thanks in advance,[image]

[image]

Comment: use the random value as the scale on the instances on points

Comment: Thanks for the reply; I think I misspoke with this first example, so I've changed the picture. Let's say I want to connect a group as an instance with several float inputs and I want random values on each of the sockets. Is there a way of achieving this?

Comment: I don't think so. I think the unreleased version 4.0 might be able to do it with the Repeat node system

Comment: @Crys you might not understand the point of instances. the point is to use less memory etc. so it's faster. once you make more changes per instance other than location rotation and scale, you start to loos the advantage. if you want to just get verity there is another way to go about. see here https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/274485/how-can-i-instantiate-a-procedural-node-group-with-different-parameters#274486

Comment: This explains the red line: [Why is there a red line when I try to connect one node to another?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/274557/). And this question has been asked before, which is why it is a duplicate: [How can I instantiate a procedural node group with different parameters?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/274485/)

Comment: OK, that's more clear for me; thank you for this fruitful discussion :):).