# Geometry Nodes: How to position an object on a point without instancing?

Tags: geometry-nodes

question seems easy, but I can't get it out - the situation: two objects, a plane and a cube. I want to position the cube on a point (vertex) of the plane, ***but without using the instance node***.

Getting the position of a point from the plane is done via the sample index node, but how to position the cube at this position?!

Thanx in advance,
H.

[image]

EDIT 1: "Set Position" with "Offset" doesn't give the desired result.

[image]

EDIT 2: Also with "Transform Geometry" I don't get the right result.

[image]

EDIT 3: node tree ungrouped for better understanding.

[image]

Comment: "Transform Geometry" node.

Comment: or set position and use offset

Comment: No, "Set Position" with "Offset" doesn't give the desired result - see added image in the first post. Thx.

Comment: No, also with "Transform Geometry" I don't get the right result - see added image in the first post. Thx.

Comment: Please ask your question in a clear manner. Using some custom group node, without showing its context definitely is not clear. https://blender.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Thanks for the reply. The group is just an index-node and a compare-node to define a specific vertex - image attached in first post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In principle, you have already done everything right here:

1. with the node `Sample Index` you get attributes of another object
2. with `Transform Geometry` you can change the position of the cube

However...

The `Sample Index` node has two modes:

- If you use fields (multiple values!) at the input *Index*, the node also provides multiple values at the output *Value* and is therefore incompatible with other nodes that require a single value
- However, if you specify a single static value at the input *Index* (for example, a simple integer value), the node also returns a single value at the output *Value* and is therefore also compatible with `Transform Geometry`.

Therefore, the solution in this case should look like this:

[image]

*(In this example, index 8 is the middle point of the grid)*

This answer explains the behavior in more detail:
[Why is there a red line when I try to connect one node to another?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/274557/)

Comment: Thank You for the answer - this works fine!