# Control "distribute points in volume" density with gradient?

Tags: geometry-nodes

Is there a way to control the density of distribution of points within a volume with a gradient *using the mesh to volume node?

I'd like to fill a sphere or cube-shaped object with points (which will be instanced objects) and give the center of the object a higher density of points than its boundary (much like a spherical gradient).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try using this setup. Its basically deletes points that are close to mesh surface using distance to a surface as probability.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Would something like that work ?
[image]
I needed to add a Multiply node with a big amount for the effect to be visible.

Comment: That looks promising, thank you! In my case, I am trying to get this to work with "mesh to volume". 

Using your example as a starting point, I've tried plugging in the gradient texture into the "mesh to volume" node but that results in a red noodle.

Comment: Yes, the gradient texture outputs a Field value (diamond shape), that can't be plugged into a Single value (round shape), hence the red noodle. Maybe that answer will help you (I can't figure it myself, but hopefuly it will give you a better understanding of the problem and some clues) [link]https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/274557/why-is-there-a-red-line-when-i-try-to-connect-one-node-to-another[/link]