# Why can't I connect the duplicate index output into the curve circle radius input?

Tags: geometry-nodes

I am trying to make the radius be based on the index of the duplicate instances, but Blender is showing a red line. I am a beginner not sure what is going on.

[image]

[image]

Comment: It seems that you have a loop between the *Duplicate Elements* node and the *Curve Circle*  node. You can not use the output socket *Duplicate Index* connected to the input socket *Radius* as the output socket *Curve* is connected to the input socket *Geometry*. About red lines, may I recommend to read this post: [Why is there a red line when I try to connect one node to another?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/274557/why-is-there-a-red-line-when-i-try-to-connect-one-node-to-another) ?

Comment: Also in this case you have a circular reference. Which node is supposed to be evaluated first? :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*(Using Blender 3.6.8)*

Nodes such as *Scale Instances*, *Translate Instances* and *Rotate Instances* are useful after a *Duplicate Elements* node set in *Instance* domain to take advantage of the *Duplicate Index* socket. However, the input geometry must be converted to an instance before, using a *Geometry to Instance* node:

[image: GN graph and results]

**Resources:** [image]

Comment: Wow..... this is exactly what I wanted, but I do have one question though..  what if I want to realize all the instances not just 5?

Comment: Could you explain what you mean by "to realize" ? Because in Blender, *realize* has a specific meaning for instances, so I am confused. Do you want to control from the modifier panel (on the right hand side of GUI) how many rings are generated ?

Comment: Like in the viewer spreadsheet thing there is only 5 instances being shown, but theres clearly WAY more then that

Comment: We have nested instances: level 1 is 5 rings, level 2 is 9 points per ring. The spreadsheet seems to display only the first level, so 5. But if you add a *Realize Instances* node just before the *Group Output* node, you will see 45 points in the spreadsheet.

Comment: Yeah but I tried that and it like reset the scale for all the points though, why does this happen?

Comment: It is because the *Realize Instances* node is making copies of the same "original" point. So all points have the same radius and scaling a point does not change its radius, only its position. To go further, could you specify if you would like to have instances (i.e. sharing properties) or individual points (i.e. with specific properties) at the output of the GN modifier? By construction of instances, you can not have both...

Comment: Sir, I just want them to be each their own indiviual points so I can have all 45, that's all I am asking but thank you for your patience and explanation of everything thus far

Comment: I figured it out! :)

Comment: Great ! Could you share your findings by editing your question and adding your updated GN graph ?