Geometry nodes: random value as single value rather than field
I want a single random number, rather than a field. In my node setup I want to sample the position of a random point on a mesh, so I'm using the sample index node and I want the index value to be random. This position value is setting the start and end point for a mesh line node, to draw a line from a random part of the mesh to another.
It works fine if I set the index manually, or use an integer node with the value set by a driver like #noise.random(0, 1234) where 1234 is the number of points on the mesh.

But if I use a Random value node the index input is a field, rather than a single value, and the tree is invalid. Is there a way other than a driver on an integer node, to create a random single value?


Related: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/274557/ ...duplicate?

Yea, it's one of probably tens of duplicates of that :P

Nodes are smart enough to know if their result is based on a field, and therefore they should return a field (exceptions are Sample Index and Attribute Statistic, which use a field to get a single value, though, as you see in your case, the former can still return a field if you connect a field to Index socket). In case of Random Value node, the implied input to the ID input is the ID node. So if you want to resign from a field, you have to connect any single value into that socket - even a dead-end Reroute will work.
Once you do that, notice the output changes from a diamond  to a diamond with a hole , which means the socket can output a field, but currently it outputs a single value instead.
And, as the GIF below shows, all inputs need to be "constant" (single value; not a field), so if you connect a field anywhere else, the output loses the dot in the socket and becomes a field again:


On the screen capture above, I'm using an implicit zero value of a reroute. However this has been considered a bug, and disconnected reroutes will now behave as a default value of a socket. Therefore instead of a reroute use an "Integer" node❗

Also, I round socket  means it only uses a single value, not a field.
