Rotate instances randomly along Z-axis in Blender 4.1+
I'd like to rotate a bunch of instances randomly  along Z-axis in Blender 4.1, but I don't want to use the deprecated Rotate Euler node. Also with the introduction of the new Rotation socket, things have become a bit more complicated than previously.

I was following Erindale's Hex World tutorial, but he didn't explain the part where he instanced several trees on top. However, this is my attempt at instancing trees and also rotating them randomly along Z-axis (which isn't working):

Please help me rotate these trees randomly along Z-axis! I'm trying multiple workarounds but none of them are working!

Try plugging the rotation into the Instance on Points node instead of the Transform Geometry node. Also, use Radians, not Degrees. As for the red line: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/274557/

Since you want to rotate each instance differently, the node Transform Geometry will unfortunately not help you.
This rotates an object, but unfortunately only a single one, which would give all your instances the same rotation.
You would therefore have to create an individual rotation for each object directly during instantiation or subsequently change the transformation of the created instances.
With this setup, you rotate the objects directly when instantiating them:

And with this setup you can rotate the instances afterwards:

Note: Also note that you also generate the correct values with Random Value. The input values must be specified in radians, which is why I use a range of $-\pi$ and $\pi$ in this example.
This example also explains why you see a red connecting line:
"Why is there a red line when I try to connect one node to another?"

About the random values for rotation: Yes, the input should be radians and I also think it is important to know that. But in cases like this, unless you do not want to limit the rotation to something lower than full circle, it doesn't matter if you enter $-\pi$ to $\pi$ or 0 to $2\pi$ or 0 to 360 interpreted as radians since it looks the same if an instance is rotated 45° or 405° or 7245°.

@GordonBrinkmann Absolutely correct, but for most people $\pi$ is easier to recognize as a number than $2\pi$, which is why I wrote it that way ;-)

Any range of length $τ$ will result with even random distribution of rotations. As for recognizing, I like to use "Math node: to radians" to input recognizable 45, 90, 180, 360 etc.
