How to sample a single point from a volume
I have this geo nodes setup that is intended to sample a single point from a volume. However, the output of the "Delete Geometry" node is usually 0 to 3 vertices. I would expect a single vertex. What am I doing wrong?

Thanks!

The problem here is that Random Value does not generate unique values and the same number may be repeated multiple times. However, you can create a single value with the node by plugging an integer value into the input ID.

Related: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/274557/

In addition to what Daniel Möller spotted (and also fixed in his setup), you have an Off-by-one error.
Indices are 0-based, they start at zero. This means that for $n$ points, the last point has index $n-1$. The error you're getting is one reason why many programming languages define ranges by inclusive start and exclusive end, e.g. in Python:
>>> list(range(0, 5))
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4]

However "Random Value" node can yield the "Max" value, both in "Integer" and "Float" modes:

Imgur mirror (SE image hosting has problems)
What I don't understand is why you don't pick just the first point, and delete all other, as those are random points anyway. Perhaps they aren't exactly random as explained here:
How to randomly distribute a specific number of instances?
But we have a modern solution to that: just randomize their order and then keep the first:

Imgur mirror
non-zero integers are TRUE by implicit coercion, so all but the first point are removed.

Nice, good catch!

Have you ever tested the performance of this? Sorting is usually slower than simple 1 to 1 booleans. For a big number of elements, this might make a significant difference.

@DanielMöller but he wants a single point, not a big number of elements

The number is dependent on the "distribute", not on how many he wants. To sort even 1 point, it's necessary to compare it to every other. A well implemented solution might be ok for 1 point, but 2 is double the number of operations compared with a simple compare.

@DanielMöller the performance cost doesn't matter even if there's 100 of points to sort. It's insignificant.

It's interesting, sorting has a speed limit of O(n log(n)), but shuffling can be done in O(n)... I like this idea too! I'm used to Houdini where order is randomized by default.

Okay, I just changed this to the accepted answer because I discovered that if I use the method proposed in the other answer, the points always seem to come from the same cluster of the volume, oddly enough. This one appears to produce purely random sampling from within the volume.

Connect some constant value to the ID of the random value, otherwise, you're getting a different random value for each point. So it will be just a mess. What you want is the same random value for all points.

