Random values in Repeat Zone
I want to randomize the position of each cube in the repeat zone across the x and y plane. It appears the random value node cannot be used in the repeat zone. I understand there are alternative ways to randomize the positions, e.g. I can use instancing instead of the repeat zone. However, for the specific animation I want to create, the cubes need to be generated iteratively, not instanced. In short, I need to use the repeat zone. Is there a way to get the random value node to work in the repeat zone? And if not, is there an intuitive explanation as to why it is not possible?


Here is the requested "intuitive explanation": https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/274557/why-is-there-a-red-line-when-i-try-to-connect-one-node-to-another/

There are 2 problems here:

Randomness in software is generally "pseudorandom". You take something as a seed, and transform it in a way it's impractical to predict the result. In Geometry Nodes the "random" nodes are additionally deterministic, because they don't use system time as part of the seed, therefore running the program multiple times will generate the same random number each time (as long as the program is not modified). This means on each iteration of a repeat zone, you will get the same values from a "random" node, until you figure a way to modify the seed on each iteration.

"Random Value" node outputs a field, because it gets a field input hidden in the "ID" socket. A field cannot be connected to sockets that don't accept fields, and that's why you get a red link (nothing to do with a repeat zone). You can override it with an explicit non-field input like here (notice the warning about a fixed bug).


You can hit two birds with one stone by connecting Iteration to ID:

Imgur mirror (SE image hosting has problems)
